# SQL Server DATENAME() Function en español

Tags: sql-server

Tengo estas querys pero me arrojan los datos en ingles y los necesito en español, existe alguna manera de hacer eso?
Gracias

```html
declare @Fecha date
SET @Fecha = GetDate() 
go

DATENAME(day, @Fecha) as Dia, 
DATENAME(weekday,@Fecha) as DiaSemana,  
DATENAME(month, @Fecha) as Mes, 
DATENAME(YEAR, @Fecha) as Año,

Dia DiaSemana  Mes     Año
7   Monday    January  2019
```

Y necesito que dia y mes sean en español

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Antes de ejecutar la funcion debes especificar el idioma con el que vas a trabajar:

```
SET Language 'Spanish';

declare @Fecha date
SET @Fecha = GetDate() 
go

DATENAME(day, @Fecha) as Dia, 
DATENAME(weekday,@Fecha) as DiaSemana,  
DATENAME(month, @Fecha) as Mes, 
DATENAME(YEAR, @Fecha) as Año,

Dia DiaSemana  Mes     Año
7   Lunes    Enero  2019
```